# How to iterate over a String, char by char, in Dart?

Tags: string, list, dictionary, dart, character

I don't see Dart strings treated as lists of characters. I assume I have to use for loops, which would be lame.

Comment: What do you mean by "char"? Codepoint? Grapheme cluster? Byte?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

An alternative implementation (working with characters outside the basic multilingual plane):

```
"A string".runes.forEach((int rune) {
  var character=new String.fromCharCode(rune);
  print(character);
});
```

Comment: Starting with Dart 2.7.0, you can use the package `characters`: https://pub.dev/packages/characters.

Comment: BonusPoint:: getter codeUnits can also be used in place of runes as in:```"A string".codeUnits.forEach((int c) {
  var character=new String.fromCharCode(c);
  print(character);
});```

Comment: `String.codeUnits` only deals with UTF-16 code points, whereas `String.runes` deals with Unicode code points (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32). A character can be represented by 2 UTF-16 code points (i.e. a surrogate pair), but will be represented by only 1 rune.

Comment: @CedX Almost.  As the name implies, `String.codeUnits` deals with UTF-16 code *units*; a code *unit* is an encoded portion of a Unicode code *point*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Terminology

Comment: This should not be used, try it with "A string ‍" as input. you will split the last visual character into its components:


♂

Answer (score 37):

You could also use the [split method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/split.html) to generate a `List` of characters.

```dart
input.split('').forEach((ch) => print(ch));
```

Answer (score 34):

Unfortunately [strings](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_core/String.html) are currently not iterable so you would have to use a for loop like this

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  var char = s[i];
}
```

Note that Dart does not have a character class so **string[index]** will return another string.

Comment: Warning: with some rare foreign languages, the loop does not work as expected. `length` property and `[]` operator refers to UTF-16 code units, not characters. Some characters can use 2 UTF-16 code units.

Comment: And most emojis.

Answer (score 8):

With Flutter [Characters Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/characters/Characters-class.html)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
var characters = aString.characters;
```

Comment: The Flutter link is a re-export of [`package:characters/characters.dart`](https://pub.dev/documentation/characters/latest/) which can be used without Flutter too.
It is the recommended way to iterate general Unicode text.

Answer (score 3):

Extension to properly iterate a `String`:

```dart
extension on String {

  /// To iterate a [String]: `"Hello".iterable()`
  Iterable<String> iterable() sync* {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      yield this[i];
    }}}
```

Use it like this:

```dart
expect("Hello".iterable(), ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]);
```

---

However, if you add the [Characters package](https://pub.dev/packages/characters):

```dart
import "package:characters/characters.dart";
```

Then you can have an extension to properly iterate a `String` using both simple characters or Unicode graphemes:

```dart
extension on String {

  /// To iterate a [String]: `"Hello".iterable()`
  /// This will use simple characters. If you want to use Unicode Grapheme
  /// from the [Characters] library, passa [chars] true.
  Iterable<String> iterable({bool unicode = false}) sync* {
    if (unicode) {
      var iterator = Characters(this).iterator;
      while (iterator.moveNext()) {
        yield iterator.current;
      }
    } else
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        yield this[i];
      }
  }
}
```

To prove it works:

```dart
  test('String.iterable()', () {
    expect("Hello".iterable(), ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]);
    expect("Hello".iterable(unicode: true), ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]);

    expect("".iterable().length, 2);
    expect("".iterable().map((s) => s.codeUnitAt(0)), [55357, 56842]);

    expect("".iterable(unicode: true).length, 1);
    expect("".iterable(unicode: true), [""]);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension on String {
  //toArray1 method
  List toArray1() {
    List items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      items.add(this[i]);
    }
    return items;
  }

  //toArray2 method
  List toArray2() {
    List items = [];
    this.split("").forEach((item) => items.add(item));
    return items;
  }
}

main(List<String> args) {
  var str = "hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world";
  final stopwatch1 = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(str.toArray1());
  print('str.toArray1() executed in ${stopwatch1.elapsed}');

  final stopwatch2 = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(str.toArray2());
  print('str.toArray2() executed in ${stopwatch2.elapsed}');


}
```

The above is the example of using for loop and foreach but the result i tested, foreach is working way faster than for loop. Sorry if i was wrong, but it was my tests.

Answer (score 1):

This also can be the solution : use it if you find it easy

```
String text = "findlastcharacter";
var array = text.split('');
array.forEach((element) { 
 print(element); // iterating char by char 
});
String lastchar = array[array.length - 1];
print('last char is = $lastchar'); // last char is = r
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:characters/characters.dart';  
      
String myString = "Hi";
for (var char in myString.characters) {
   print(char);
}
H
i
```

One thing to be aware of if you are starting with Characters is that they will be converted to String.

```
Characters myCharacters = "Hi.characters".characters;      
for (var char in myCharacters) {
        assert(char is String);
        print(char);
}
H
i
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick overview, you should defenetly use the characters package:

```dart
import "package:characters/characters.dart";

main() {
  print("‍♂️".characters);
  print("‍♂️".characters.length);
  print("‍♂️".runes);
  print("‍♂️".runes.length);
  print("‍♂️".codeUnits);
  print("‍♂️".codeUnits.length);
}
```

will output

```
‍♂️
1
(129492, 8205, 9794, 65039)
4
[55358, 56788, 8205, 9794, 65039]
5
```